# How to differentiate between a file URI and contentprovider URI?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Suppose I'm selecting a file externally via:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and in the result is returned via `onActivityResult`

```
Uri file = data.getData();
```

This can be in different formats. What is the convention here to determine if a content resolver query is needed? If the file URI is a file path `file:///` or a app URI like `//package.example/...`.

I know I could check if the uri has a `file:///` prefix but that seems a bit hacky. I just want the file path.

Comment: "I just want the file path" - Then you need `getPath()` from `Uri` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the convention here to determine if a content resolver query is needed?

`openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` handles both the `file` scheme and the `content` scheme.

> I know I could check if the uri has a file:/// prefix but that seems a bit hacky

Um, well, `Uri` has [a `getScheme()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme()).

> I just want the file path.

There is no "file path" for a `content` `Uri`, as there is no requirement that the content be stored as a file.

Answer (score 2):

Just to compliment CommonsWare answer. You can examine the scheme of the URI, using, for example, [getScheme()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme()) method, as mentioned in CommonsWare's answer. A content provider URI scheme is [content://](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), while a file URI scheme is file://